# Crystal Reports - Sorting two different date fields chronologically

Tags: sorting, date, crystal-reports, report, field

I've got two date fields from two tables and I'm trying to show receipts of POs in line with work order consumption sorted chronologically.

Is there any way to sort two date fields together?

For instance:

```
1/1/14 work order date
1/5/14 work order date
1/7/14 PO receipt date
1/9/14 work order date
1/20/14 work order date
```

The two fields are 'duedate' from table 'porel' and 'reqdate' from table 'jobmtl'

Comment: Are the two tables linked in some manner?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the simplest solution in such cases is to perform the ordering at the server side (e.g. using SQL Server stored procedure, Access query, etc.), and then use the stored procedure or query as the source for the data.

An alternative that I read about is to create global variables in the report, assign your dates values to these variables using 'WhilePrintingRecords;' in formula fields, and using these variables that then does the actual reporting for you.

Slightly complicated.

Another solution which I am not sure if applies to you is :

1. Click on the main menu > Report > Record Sort Expert
2. Select your date field in the box on the left and add it to the box on the right
3. Check the Ascending checkbox and click Ok

Let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

you should create a formula saying

```
if (table1.duedate = null) then
   {table2.duedate}
else  
   {table1.duedate}
```

Then sort on this formula. Check the syntax yourself.